# Android app to change the name of installed apps

Tags: gratis, android

Am looking for an Android app that has the ability to change the name of installed apps. I prefer a free app. Also the app should provide the facility to change the name back to its original(its not mandatory). Is there any ?

Comment: Are you trying to change the name in the launcher or change the name of the actual app?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I just want to change the name in the launcher(where ever the app icon is displayed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a different launcher. [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) allows you to change the name of each app. If you long-press an app within the app draw. Although it does not store the original name, you can modify it again to display the original app name.

[image]